# Producer#initTransactions doesn't work with KafkaContainer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, testcontainers

I try to send messages to Kafka with a transaction. So, I use this code:

```
 try (Producer<Void, String> producer = createProducer(kafkaContainerBootstrapServers)) {
            producer.initTransactions();
            producer.beginTransaction();
            Arrays.stream(messages).forEach(
                message -> producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(KAFKA_INPUT_TOPIC, message)));
            producer.commitTransaction();
        }
```

...

```
private static Producer<Void, String> createProducer(String kafkaContainerBootstrapServers) {
        return new KafkaProducer<>(
            ImmutableMap.of(
                ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaContainerBootstrapServers,
                ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
                ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG, true,
                ProducerConfig.TRANSACTIONAL_ID_CONFIG, UUID.randomUUID().toString()
            ),
            new VoidSerializer(),
            new StringSerializer());
    }
```

If I use local Kafka, it works well.

But if I use Kafka TestContainers, it freezes on `producer.initTransactions()`:

```
private static final String KAFKA_VERSION = "4.1.1";

@Rule
public KafkaContainer kafka = new KafkaContainer(KAFKA_VERSION)
    .withEmbeddedZookeeper();
```

How can I configure KafkaContainer to work with transactions?

Comment: You should look into createProducer(). I believe it is not setting up enable.idempotence. Sample configuration is shown at https://www.baeldung.com/kafka-exactly-once

Comment: I set "ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG, true".

Comment: Few more things to check: 1. Check the version of Kafka. 2. One can configure Kafka to prevent producers from creating Topic. In such case, you may need to contact admin to create a topic for you.

Comment: Locally I have 2.1.1 Kafka version. But with TestContainerts it doesn't work even with the same version, 5.1.1 for Confluent Platform - 2.1.1 for Kafka (https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/versions-interoperability.html#cp-and-apache-kafka-compatibility).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [Kafka for JUnit](https://mguenther.github.io/kafka-junit/) instead of Kafka testcontainers. I had the same problem with transactions and made them alive in this way.

Maven dependency that I used:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.mguenther.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-junit</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got an exception using [Kafka for JUnit](https://mguenther.github.io/kafka-junit/) as @AntonLitvinenko suggested. My question about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55360327/8253837).

I added this dependency to fix it (see the [issue](https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/CURATOR-446)):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.curator</groupId>
    <artifactId>curator-test</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
           <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
            <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Also, I used `2.0.1` version for kafka-junit and kafka_2.11:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>${kafkaVersion}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```