# How to fix Kafka for JUnit dependencies problem?

Tags: junit, apache-kafka

I want to use [Kafka for JUnit](https://mguenther.github.io/kafka-junit/), so I added this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.mguenther.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-junit</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Locally it works well. But on Jenkins I get an error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFound scala/math/Ordering

If I add `scala-library` dependency (version `2.1.12`), I get:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFound com.typesafe.scalalogging.Logger$

Also, I have several `Apache Beam` dependencies with `2.9.0` version.

What can I check to solve this issue?

**UPD**:

If I add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.charithe</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-junit</artifactId>
    <version>${kafkaJunit.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I get:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/MatchError

If I add `scala-library` (version `2.1.12`), I get:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)[Ljava/lang/Object;

And with the last version, I get:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFound com.typesafe.scalalogging.Logger$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPD**

I got an exception using [Kafka for JUnit](https://mguenther.github.io/kafka-junit/) as @AntonLitvinenko suggested. My question about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55360327/8253837).

I added this dependency to fix it (see the [issue](https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/CURATOR-446)):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.curator</groupId>
    <artifactId>curator-test</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
           <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
            <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Also, I used `2.0.1` version for kafka-junit and kafka_2.11:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>${kafkaVersion}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

---

**OLD**

I decided to use another Kafka-JUnit library by [Salesforce](https://github.com/salesforce/kafka-junit). I added this group of dependencies:

```
<!-- Declare kafka-junit4 dependency -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.salesforce.kafka.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- Include Kafka 2.0.x -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

And now my test works well.

You can see the usage instructions of this library [here](https://github.com/salesforce/kafka-junit/tree/master/kafka-junit4).

I tried to increase Kafka version to 2.1.1 and I have an exception:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Function1

So, I think the main problem is used Kafka version.